# Why am I getting error code 4 while testing the communication with Bosch BMA456 sensor on STM32F411RE using STM32CubeIDE?

Tags: stm32, sensors, stm32cubeide, nucleo

**BMA456 test communication error with STM32F411RE**

Hello everyone!

I am working with the Bosch BMA456 sensor, and I am willing to activate the step counter feature. However, before getting to that part, I decided the play it by the books and follow the instructions provided by the BMA456 Datasheet (Page 11, Example1 - Testing communication with the BMA456).

After debugging a little, I found that I am receiving the error code "4". I am using the STM32CubeIDE as well. You can find my whole main.c code below.

I really hope that someone can help me with this!
Thanks a lot.

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bma456.h"
//#include "bma456.c"
#include "bma4.h"
//#include "bma4.c"
#include "bma4_defs.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */
#define BMA456_I2C_ADDRESS 0x19
#define BMA456_CHIP_ID_REG 0x00
#define BMA456_CHIP_ID_VAL 0x16
/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

char buf[50];

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

uint8_t BMA456_ReadChipID(uint32_t *errorCode) {
    uint8_t chip_id = 0;
    HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, BMA456_I2C_ADDRESS, BMA456_CHIP_ID_REG, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, &chip_id, 1, 1000);

    if (status != HAL_OK) {
        *errorCode = HAL_I2C_GetError(&hi2c1);
        // Handle error here
        return 0;
    }
    return chip_id;
}

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    uint32_t errorCode = 0;
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  // Initialize BMA456 step counter

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      uint8_t chip_id = BMA456_ReadChipID(&errorCode);

        if (chip_id == BMA456_CHIP_ID_VAL) {
            // Communication is OK
            strcpy((char*)buf, "Data received!!!\r\n");
            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, buf, strlen((char*)buf), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
            HAL_Delay(2000);
        } else {
            // Communication is not OK
             sprintf((char*)buf, "Error code: %lu\r\n", errorCode);
            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, buf, strlen((char*)buf), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
            HAL_Delay(2000);
        }

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
//  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 1000000;
//  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 400000;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: What does `BMA456_ReadChipID()` do? Your logic seems inverted - you print the error code if the chip ID is not correct. Surely you should only consider the chip ID if the error code is OK? Does the documentation for the driver you are using say what error code `4` means?

Comment: The BMA456_ReadChipID() is a function that I have defined above the "int main" code. What it does is the following: It uses the variables that I defined earlier in the code and uses them to perform a sort of communication with the I2C-based memory BMA456 sensor.

Let me know if I can clarify it better. And unfortunately, the documentation does not mention an error code "4" at all, nor other error codes.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define HAL_I2C_ERROR_AF                0x00000004U    /*!< AF error              */
```

It means that your chip did not acknowledged the address.

What can be a source of this poriblem:

1. You pass the wrong address.
2. Your device is not working
3. You did not configure the I2C peripheral and/or related GPIOs correctly

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First, may I ask where did you get this define from? I am curious, perhaps I have missed something. Now let's try to reduce the 3 possible sources of the problem that you provided.

1- The wrong address: I assume you mean the BMA456_I2C address?
2- It can be the case.
3- Is there a way to properly check if my configuration is wrong or correct? I am still a beginner when it comes to using STMCubeIDE to configure the Pins.

Thanks!

Comment: See the definition of the function.

Comment: Which function exactly? Could you please elaborate? Thank you dear.

Comment: @Johnny HAL I2C functions that accept an address expect you to shift the address left by one bit before passing it to the HAL function. So you might want to look into that.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I will test it out and come back here with the results.

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar issue recently, shifting the address to the left worked for me:
`#define BMA456_I2C_ADDRESS 0x19 << 1`